# Eclipse 3.2.2 content assist not finding classes in the project

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-3.2

In Eclipse 3.2.2 on Linux content assist is not finding classes within the same project. Upgrading above 3.2 is not an option as SWT is not available above 3.2 for Solaris.

I have seen suggestions to clean the workspace, reopen the workspace, run eclipse with the `-clean` command, none of which has worked.

Comment: No I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your last comment it worked partially.
If there is any kind of errors, the content assist wont work. Once fixed, it partially works.
I say partially because, there appear to be a bug, when I do Perl EPIC inheritance ex:

```
package FG::CatalogueFichier;
use FG::Catalogue;
our @ISA = qw(FG::Catalogue);
use strict;
```

, the inheritted subroutines are not displayed in the content assist.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced in Preferences, and make sure that the correct proposal kinds are selected. Same kind of thing happened to me when I first moved to 3.4.

Comment: I have tried multiple things in the content assist preferences including:

    * Turning off all content assist, cleaning, then re-enabling
    * Turning on all content assist, then cleaning
    * Restoring defaults on content assist, then cleaning
    * Most of the in between

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that "build automatically" in the Project menu is checked? :-)

Another thing: is the Problems view, unfiltered, completely clear of compilation errors and of classpath errors?

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes find I "lose" content assist because the "content assist computers" get disabled.

This is in:

```
[Workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings

org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
```

and I just have to remove this property:
content_assist_disabled_computers=