# Eclipse is very slow when using Code Assist (org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui.javaAllCompletionProposalComputer)

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, mylyn

Can you guess what happens?

I generated a client stub using Eclipse WTP [Axis2] and while working on
a client I get Eclipse working very slowly when it tries to use Code Assist,
that is, press a dot to get a list of methods,
there's up to 30 seconds hang-ups of the workbench.

eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_15
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Warning
Fri Jan 22 16:40:51 MSK 2010
The 'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui.javaAllCompletionProposalComputer' proposal computer from the 'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui' plug-in did not complete normally. The extension took too long to return from the 'computeCompletionProposals()' operation.

Comment: Can you update or disable the plugin? Or is that central to javaing on Eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367306/eclipse-java-content-assist-not-working ?

Comment: updating/disabling didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for those interested:
the only solution I found is get back to the Ganymede (The most recent version today is Galileo 3.5.1).

I tried Galileo Classic and Galileo 3.5.1 Java EE, both freshly downloaded, neither worked with that project.
Eclipse hangs up and uses 100% of CPU resource.

Ganymede works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I was mucking with eclipse.ini and doubled the XXMaxPermSize to 512M. According to Sun:

MaxPermSize specifies the the maximum size for the permanent generation heap, a heap that holds objects such as classes and methods.

Like magic, the hang is gone. I would not be surprised if Eclipse uses the permanent generation heap to store/sort candidates for Content Assist and thrashes if the heap gets overloaded.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted that explanation of the PermGen heap.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Increased heap, changed VM, nothing worked.  Until I found that one of my dependencies was a library shared via network drive.  I copied the JAR locally and changed the dependency.  My hang time went away.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. This is due to an error in workspace. My solution is get rid of error workspace, switch to another workspace folder and import my projects again.

Answer (score 0):

If Mylyn is not used another solution could be to disable the automatic activation of the Mylyn plug-ins on startup: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown

This did it for me.