# Eclipse Content Assist works really slow and sometimes shows a pop up with problems. How to fix?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I have noticed recently that when I type Ctrl+Space (Content Assist shortcut) in Eclipse (in order to autocomplete the code I write), the process hangs for a bit before, sometimes getting really slow, and sometimes giving this error:

[image]

Why that happens? Should I do something in order to fix this annoying issue?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117880/eclipse-is-very-slow-when-using-code-assist-org-eclipse-mylyn-java-ui-javaallco

Comment: I am sorry, you are telling me to downgrade to Eclipse Ganymede like the user of the accepted answer tells? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117880/eclipse-is-very-slow-when-using-code-assist-org-eclipse-mylyn-java-ui-javaallco#answer-2132399

Comment: Have you tried to increase the heap size?

Comment: No I didn't how do I do that?

Comment: It's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5130171/2128755

Comment: Sorry, where is the eclipse.ini located in a STS installation on a Mac? I tried to use find but it seems there are several eclipse.ini files:

`./sts-bundle/sts-3.6.2.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.test_1.1.0.v20131211-1531/dataFile/readerTest1/eclipse.ini`


`./sts-bundle/sts-3.6.2.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build.tests_1.1.500.v20140423-0753/resources/264743/build1/features/ee/bin/carbon/macosx/ppc/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini`

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Overview

Comment: Thanks for the link, if I do not have the $ECLIPSE_HOME env var set and inside STS.app/Contents/MacOS I don't have any eclipse.ini, what can I do? Create one inside this dir? But what content should I put inside the file?

Comment: depends on your OS. I suggest to download an eclipse package and copy&paste the ini-file.

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by corrupted jars in classpath.

If your project is maven project, try to find and remove partially downloaded jars.

Assumes that all your jars resident in `~/.m2/repository`：

`find ~/.m2/repository -name "*-in-progress" | xargs dirname | xargs rm -rf`