# Eclipse Content Assist Slowness with large projects

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I am facing extreme slowness in Java Content Assist with a large java project in Eclipse. The project has a lot of dependent jars (>100). I'm not really sure if the slowness is due to the dependent jars, but I'm guessing thats the case.

Have any of you faced similar issues? I changed the Activation Delay to 500ms to reduce the pain but I still get the "Problems with Content Assist" pop up that suggest disabling Mylyn. I also set the following timeout flag.

-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.ui.codeAssistTimeout=60000

It does not seem to have helped.

-Xmx is set to 900m. I am using a dual core 3 GHz Windows XP 32-bit box with 4 GB RAM.

I would welcome any suggestions or solutions you may have.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you used a decent `eclipse.ini`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a bug whereby if you have large complex Jars in your workspace the Content Assist will slow down to the point of being unusable. See [my question here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367306/eclipse-java-content-assist-not-working).

The bug has been fixed but I can't tell if it's in the current release.

Comment: Damo, I did read this earlier and initially thought this may not be related, but reading the eclipse bug report again tells me this could be the same issue. But, according to this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=289057 this is already resolved and should be a part of Eclipse 3.6 which is what I'm using. Unfortunately, I use Mylyn a lot so I'm reluctant to disable it.

Comment: I had the problem in 3.6M2. It says it's fixed in 3.6M6 but I couldn't see it listed as a fixed bug in the downloads page. As a test try removing the biggest 10 or 20 jars from the classpath and project and see if that helps the Content Assist.

Answer (score 2):

If any of those jars or the content in the project are not on a fast, local disk, put them on a fast, local disk.

Comment: I had this issue.  It took +10seconds to get a response at times.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mylyn? If not... disabling the Mylyn content assist will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a Remote Systems project where JARs were configured from the remote system's `/lib` folder. I just imported all relevant JARs locally, configured the build path to use these local JARs instead of the remote ones, and Bob's your uncle! The issue is gone!