# Eclipse 'computeCompletionProposals()' Error

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has been working very well for me recently, up until now. I am using Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a), and whenever I am typing, it seems that when I press the '.' key, it slows down the whole program for about 5 seconds. It is very laggy and annoying to work with. Here is the error I get:

[image: Here is the error I get:]

I have checked my metadata.log file but there are no errors. Although I can still use Eclipse, it is just annoying to use currently. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I checked another post and it said it may be due to large JAR files. I have a craftbukkit.jar file for Minecraft plugins. Any idea if this could be the problem?

EDIT: I have reinstalled and it is still not working.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367306/eclipse-java-content-assist-not-working

Comment: I've tried a lot of what was suggested, couldn't fix the problem, but thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Eclipse from fresh?

Comment: What do you mean 'from fresh'? Good idea to reinstall though, I could try it.

Comment: I meant like deleting all eclipse data and reinstalling. Maybe "from scratch" is a better term