# Eclipse extreme slow at auto completion

Tags: java, eclipse

i have the following Problem: 
I have a maven project and in these project eclipse is very slow. Sometimes it freeze for serveral seconds. And if want to use auto completion it takes up to one minute before this message is shown:

> The 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaAllCompletionProposalComputer' proposal computer from the 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' plug-in did not complete normally. The extension took too long to return from the 'computeCompletionProposals()' operation.

I can fix that issue by disable java proposals under content assist -> advanced. But then the auto completion wont work anymore.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you have? Which additional plug-ins do you have installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse Java Content Assist not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367306/eclipse-java-content-assist-not-working)

Comment: how can i set the Java environment variable for eclipse? I use Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)

Answer (score 3):

Try to change these memory values to **eclipse.ini** file (In your eclipse directory)

> -Xms1024m
>
> -Xmx4096m

These values depends on your system.

Comment: Try to disable some validations in eclipse preferences. Maybe your system is slow. Or try to give more memory to eclipse, maybe 2048M

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but after i deleted the .metadata folder in my workspace everything works correctly now.
Thanks for your help guys :)

Edit: thanks for the comments, a better solution would be the way howlger decripded in his comment.

Comment: **Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder** as this folder contains not only cache data but also things you want to keep (local history, non-shared launch configurations, ...). Instead, try to start Eclipse with `-clean` or try to start Eclipse with a new workspace (`-data <path-to-empty-workspace-directory>`) and to import the projects from the old workspace (_File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace_).